# Photobox lightbox - jQuery selector, using :parent to find link to an img

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, lightbox, parent

I am using a lightbox plugin called photobox. To get the thumbnails to show up in the popup, the plugin searches for the image as a child of the link to open the popup. When the image is not a child, there is a setting to set the path, in this case, a sibling:

```
$('#gallery').photobox('a', {thumb:'+ img'});
```

I have the following html where the image is not a child of the link :

```
<figure class="item" >
<img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="image">
<figcaption>
    <div class="figcaption-wrap">
         <h3>Hover</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolar.</p>
      <a href="http://placehold.it/500x400" class="photobox">View</a> 
    </div>
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

I have tried

```
$('#gallery').photobox('a', {thumb:'figcaption:parent img'});
```

but being a novice, I am not getting it to work. Any help or direction is appreciated

Comment: I'm afraid you can't go upwards using selectors...

Comment: Not with .parent() either? (obviously multiple parents)

Comment: It wouldn't work anyways.  Looking at the source for the plugin, the code searches the descendents of the link for the path that was set in thumb

Comment: @Mike `.parent()` is a function, not a selector...

Comment: I know. It was a side question as to going upwards.

Comment: does plugin allow jQuery object as `thumb`? If so can use parent there

Comment: The relevant code is at line 248,
https://github.com/yairEO/photobox/blob/master/photobox/jquery.photobox.js